# How to generate a random values and displays it in alphabet

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a method that displays random numbers between 1 and 26 of a specified lenght.

```
 public string RandomDigits(int length)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        string s = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            s = String.Concat(s, random.Next(1,27).ToString()+" ");

        return s;
    }
```

how can i display the returned value in alphabet.
i.e the method returns

1 10 7 2 11

i want to get
  A J G B K

Comment: Adding a language tag may help get you answers.

Comment: can i still do that

Comment: Yes, just click edit at the bottom of your question and then add the tags.

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted so that this question will be marked as answered.  If none of the answers help you then please let the person know so that they can further help.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer (see [How to accept SO answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variant of the solution that uses char instead of a defined string. This uses a char array and then converts it to a string at the end. More efficient than concatenating strings.

```
public string RandomDigits(int length)
{
    var random = new Random();
    var chars = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        chars[i] = (char) random.Next('A', ('Z' + 1));
    return string.Join(" ", chars);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public string RandomDigits(int length)
{
    // Define your char set
    var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    var random = new Random();
    string s = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        s = String.Concat(s, chars[random.Next(0,26)] +" ");

    return s;
}
```

Comment: what i needed actually was to get the alphabetic equivalent of the returned values.this not working

Comment: @Damilarejoshua This method is now returning the alphabetical equivalent  i.e. A J G B K, etc. Can you be more specific what is your desired goal?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have created a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q17BPz) for you to show the output.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var s = RandomDigits(5);

        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    public static string RandomDigits(int length)
    {
        char[] alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();

        var random = new Random();
        string s = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            s = String.Concat(s, alphabet[random.Next(0,26)] +" ");

        return s;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of a char array, use char and numbers from 0 to 25:

```
((char)('A'+$randomNumber)).ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `StringBuilder` to reduce memory allocations, and just generate a random number between [0, 26) and add it to 'A':

```
public string RandomDigits(int length)
{
    var random = new Random();
    var builder = new StringBuilder(length);

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        var offset = random.Next(0, 26);
        char c= (char)('A' + offset);
        builder.Append(c);
    }    

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

If you'd like to do something a bit more Linq-ish then try this:

```
public IEnumerable<char> YieldRandomDigits(int length)
{
    var random = new Random();
    var selector = Enumerable.Range(1,length).Select(i => (char)('A' + random.Next(0, 26)));
    return selector;
}
```

Where you can now say:

```
var s = string.Join("", YieldRandomDigits(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the smallest compute time ways to do this would be declaring an array alphabets and instead of directly using the random int , use that as index to this alphabet array

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    static public string RandomDigits(int length)
        {
            var random = new Random();
            string s = string.Empty;
            char[] alphabets = { 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                s = String.Concat(s, alphabets[random.Next(0,26)].ToString()+" ");

            Console.WriteLine(s);
            return s;
        }   

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        Console.WriteLine(RandomDigits(7));

    }


}
```

See here https://dotnetfiddle.net/AsHX32

Comment: With `1` being the `minValue` for your `random.Next` the letter/character `A` will never be selected since arrays are 0 based

Comment: Right, oversight .... i now changed the random by 1 so you would get all aphabets

Comment: haha...sorry . m just rushing off to the weekend. my bad guys . have done the correction

Answer (score 0):

thanks all.
this is actually what i needed to do

```
private String Number2String(int number, bool isCaps)
    {
       Char c = (Char)((isCaps ? 65 : 97) + (number - 1));

        return c.ToString();
    }
```

this is a method that converts number to string
then add 6 lenght of random number or any specified length of random number to a list.

```
      List<int> list = new List<int>();
        var random = new Random();
        string s = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            list.Add(random.Next(1, 27));

        }

        foreach (int li in list)
        {
            s = String.Concat(s, Number2String(li, true) + " ");
           //string use =  Number2String(li, true);

        }
        MessageBox.Show(s);
```

loop through the list and convert it to alphabet.
that is all i needed to achieve.i guess my question was not constructed well.
which could have been get the alphabet equivalent of a generated random numbers.
not getting random alphabet numbers.